# Graphics-def forcibly removed

Tags: packages, texlive, update

Texlive is trying to forcibly remove graphics-def. Any reason why it would do this? Texmaker was unable to build a pdf after running a Texlive update and with help/suggestion from here I went in a found that graphics-def was not installed. Manually reinstalling fixed my problem, but is there any reason why it was forcibly removing the package? Is there a known problem with the package that means I shouldn't be reinstalling it?

Comment: Which texlive do you run? Which collections do you have installed?

Comment: Texlive can remove stuff if it has been rearranged, then later on in the update it will install the replacement package. But as TeXnician mentions we need to know more information about your setup. Are you using the full scheme or a smaller scheme (which might have an error and forgot to include the replacement package). I always install the full scheme and have yet to observe a case where my system ended up in the wrong state.

Comment: I'm running 1.26.

Comment: How do I identify collections and schemes? I'm no power user and simply downloaded the mactex package in its entirety and ran it without any removal or streamlining if that is to what you are referring.